# C++: How to enforce derived class to set base member variables?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class with a member variable (preferably `private`) and I need to enforce derived classes to initialize it with a value based on their implementation; much like a pure virtual function.

To clarify, I want to declare a member in Base, have derived classes initialize it, and if they don't they get a compiler error. In the following code, I declared default constructor of `Base` to be `protected`. Then declared default constructor of `Derived` to be `private`.

```cpp
class Base {
private:
    int _size;

protected:
    Base(){}
    /* pure virtual methods */

public:
    Base(int size) : _size(size){} // must enforce derived to call this.
    virtual ~Base(){}

    /* more pure virtual methods */
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    Derived() {}
public:
    Derived(int size) : Base(size) {
        //Base::Base(size);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived* d1 = new Derived();    // throws an error as needed: 
                                    // "Cannot access private member declared in class 'Derived'"

    Derived* d2 = new Derived;      // throws an error as needed: 
                                    // "Cannot access private member declared in class 'Derived'"

    Derived* d3 = new Derived(5);   // works as needed

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that if another definition of `Derived` doesn't hide the default constructor. I'm still stuck with an uninitialized `Base::_size`.

I don't know if there is another way to go about this other than inheritance, because I still need derived classes to implement their own behavior for several methods declared in `Base`.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: `Base::Base(size);` this is probably not doing what you think it does. If you want to call the base class ctor, use the mem-initializer-list: `Derived(int size) : Base(size) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Having a constructor with parameter will automatically remove the default constructor. You don't need to make a private one.

Comment: @NeilKirk yes, but it does not force users to use the parameterized ctor. The default constructor is automatically created by the compiler if it was not explicitly defined by the class. Right?

Comment: @mbadawi23 a default ctor will **not** be implicitly declared if there's a user-declared ctor.

Comment: @DyP thanks for correcting me again. Any suggestions on how to achieve what I intend? Is my question clear enough? do I need to go by a different design to achieve what I need?

Comment: There isn't a good way to accomplish this. The closest I can think of is a pure virtual initializer and then using the curious recurring template pattern to call the initializer in the base constructor, but this is undefined behavior (though it will often do what you expect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the confusion about calling a base class ctor and default ctors, maybe the solution is just to not have a default ctor in `Base`?

```
class Base {
private:
    int _size;

public:
    // no default ctor
    Base(int size) : _size(size) {} // must enforce derived to call this.
    virtual ~Base(){}

    /* more pure virtual methods */
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    // no default ctor
    Derived(int size) : Base(size){
    }
    // examplary default ctor:
    //Derived() : Base(42) {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1;                   // error: no default ctor
    Derived* d2 = new Derived;    // same, but why use the free store?

    Derived d3(5);                // works as needed
    Derived* d4 = new Derived(5); // same, but why use the free store?

    return 0;
}
```

To be explicit about not having a default ctor, one could use

```
class Base {
    /* ... */
    Base() = delete;
    /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor

class Base1 {
    protected:
        Base1(int forward) {
            thingYouWantToHide = forward;
        }
    private:
        int thingYouWantToHide;
    };

```
class Derived1: public Base1 {
public:
    Derived1(): Base1(5) {}
};

class Base2 {
private:
    int value;
protected:
    Base2() {
        value = calledToGet();
    }
    virtual int calledToGet() = 0;

    virtual ~Base2() {} //shut compiler warnings up
};

class Derived2: public Base2 {
    virtual int calledToGet() {
        return 5;
    }
};

int main(int,char**) {
    Derived1 a;
    Derived2 b;
    return 0;
}
```

You may think Derived2 will work, but remember Derived2 is not constructed until Base2 is, so that virtual is an undefined reference when Base2 is being constructed.

You should use the first case, type-traits if it is a constant (static const) or fundamental to the type.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, using your `Base2` and `Derived2` I get a linker error for unresolved `Base2::calledToGet()`. Naturally because the compiler wants `Base2` to be complete.
Could you elaborate more on your proposed solution.